# asp.net mobile web for feature phones

Tags: asp.net, mobile

I have an existing website done in asp.net webforms .net V4. Visual studio 2010
I want to add a simple mobile section to the site for low end feature phones.

Where do I start?
Do I just do a redirect on detection of a mobile device, and jump to a page with a VERY simple UI? or must I use a special framework for it to render correctly? Should I be using a WAP site?

Note that this is for very low end phones

Answer (score 0):

Either you can redirect the user on detecting that he is using a mobile device or make some thing entirely new using phone gap or something.

Comment: thanks but not really answering me. i am looking at how best to I am looking for how best to render the page. Seems like i have to go with System.Mobile.UI because of the old phone models in the south african market. but there is no decent ui designer for it in VS2010

Comment: in that case i suggest u stick to html and javascript-ajax